# Python regex to find string

Tags: python, regex

Can someone please help with making a regex expression to accomplish the following:

Match the string '55' that is not preceded by a '$' and not directly preceded or followed by another numeric digit.

Cant work out the lookarounds. The examples I've found like `(?<!)` aren't supported by online regex testers like regexpal.

Comment: What do you mean by "regex testers"? Are you going to use a "regex tester" in your code or `re`? What have you tried?

Comment: If you want to use online regex help tools, make sure to use [one that supports Python regexes](https://regex101.com/), and put it in Python mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the regex you are looking for is just `(?<!\$)55(?!\d)`.

BTW. I use regex101.com for online regex testing. It supports `(?<!)`. Python's own library re also supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[^\$]55[^\d]
```

You can try online as mentioned.